# Count number of vertically stacked names in field of column of dataframe

Tags: r

I have column (covenant) in data frame `df1`, where each field has stacked names which are vertically concatenated, as following:

```
Insurance
Environmental
Use of Loans
Chg Fiscal Yr
ERISA
Cons,Merger,Acq
Inventory
Debt
Affiliate Trans
Liens,Encum,Mtg
Collat,Ast Sale
Debt-EBITDA
FixChg Cov
Capital Expend
Capital Expend
Debt Services
Int Cov
Int Cov
Capial Expend 
Int Cov
```

I would like to count the number of vertically stacked names. For example, about stacked field has 20 names stacked. So, it should return 20. As I know, `splitstackshape` package is there to split the stacked data but would like to know how I can count the stacked names such as above.

Comment: How about `nrow(df1)`? Question is not clear, what do you mean by " which are vertically concatenated"?

Comment: ...or maybe `length(unique(df1[["covenant"]]))` if you want to count each name only once?

Comment: @zx8754 All these names are in one field. These are in one row.

Comment: So your above example dataframe has dim of 1 row 1 column,  output of `dim(df1)`?

Comment: @Bernhard I do not need the unique names. All these names are stacked in a single cell/field. I would like to count them regardless of uniqueness.

Comment: @zx8754 My original dataframe is very large. This is just for example.  In the example above, has only 1 row and 1 column. That is why I mentioned it is stacked.

Comment: If possible please post the commands you used to generate `df1` or the output of `dput(df1)`. Else others have to guess the format of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the format of your data right, this should work and give a data frame of the same size as x with the number of items in each cell as values.

```
newdf <- data.frame(
       # iterate over columns
       lapply(df1, function(y){
           # iterate over rows
           unname(sapply(y, function(x){
             # split at linebreak and get vector length
             length(strsplit(x, "\n")[[1]])
           }))
         })
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

Split on new line then get lengths:

```
# dummy data: with 2 rows for x, 1st has 5 names, 2nd has 8 names.
df1 <- data.frame(covenant = c("Insurance
Environmental
Use of Loans
Chg Fiscal Yr
ERISA",
                 "Insurance
Environmental
Use of Loans
Chg Fiscal Yr
ERISA
Cons,Merger,Acq
Inventory
Debt"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# split on new line then get the lengths
lengths(lapply(df1$covenant, function(i) unlist(strsplit(i, split = "\n"))))
# [1] 5 8
```

Comment: I am copy pasting your solution and it's returning 2 only. It's not splitting.

Comment: @user3669801 update your post with reproducible example object, output of `dput(head(df1))`. Your newline character might be different.

Comment: The solution of @snaut worked for me. Anyways, thank you so much for your solution.

Comment: @user3669801 Try again, if snaut's solution worked then mine should work, too. As we both using split on new line character, then getting lengths, snout is using `length()` in a loop and I am using just `lengths`.